# Dynamic Header in a SPA using react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm fairly new to react and am building my own SPA right now.

The current layout of my App.js file is close to this:

```
<div className="h-100">
  <Header></Header>
  <div className="">
    <Route exact path='/' component={Construction}></Route>
    <Route path='/impressum' component={Impressum}></Route>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the layout of the Header component depending on which Route is currently selected.
What is the best way to determine that? My go to solution would be by current URL but I don't know whether there is a better way.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "change the layout"? (Add a different class for styling, place it in a different place in the DOM, include different child element, etc)

Comment: I want to disable animations i made with scroll magic, and maybe create a different layout if the one i currently have doesnt work out. All changes i want to make will be within the Header class itself.

Comment: Well, if the header will vary a lot based on the route, it might be more appropriate to include it at the top of each page component, e.g. `Construction` could include it with certain parameters, and `Impressum` could use others.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. but i currently cant find out how to pass parameters when Implementing my Header class in the other Components

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you